# Clone inputs with jquery and can't retrieve data in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm new to jquery and this is my first post on a forum, so I apologise in advance if this isn't clear. I'll try to answer your questions as best I can.

I have a small problem with a script to clone inputs. When I submit my form, I can't retrieve the values of the cloned inputs.

I've tried serialising them using jquery but I can't get the values back either. I've tried append(), appendTo(), html() but nothing changes.

Here is the html code and the script

```html
<tbody id="prods">
    <tr class="border-bottom border-bottom-dashed" type="section" id="sectionToClone">
        <td colspan="6" class="p-2">
            <input name="sections[1]" value="Première section"
                class="form-control form-control-solid section"
                type="text" placeholder="Nom de votre section..." />

        </td>
        <td class="pt-5 p-2"
            style="width:100%;
            text-align: center;">
            <button style="display: inline-block;"
                class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-active-color-primary up">
                <!--begin::Svg Icon | path: /var/www/preview.keenthemes.com/kt-products/docs/metronic/html/releases/2023-07-21-074234/core/html/src/media/icons/duotune/arrows/arr073.svg-->
                <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-3"><svg width="24"
                        height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path
                            d="M12.5657 11.3657L16.75 15.55C17.1642 15.9643 17.8358 15.9643 18.25 15.55C18.6642 15.1358 18.6642 14.4643 18.25 14.05L12.7071 8.50716C12.3166 8.11663 11.6834 8.11663 11.2929 8.50715L5.75 14.05C5.33579 14.4643 5.33579 15.1358 5.75 15.55C6.16421 15.9643 6.83579 15.9643 7.25 15.55L11.4343 11.3657C11.7467 11.0533 12.2533 11.0533 12.5657 11.3657Z"
                            fill="currentColor" />
                    </svg>
                </span>
                <!--end::Svg Icon-->
            </button>
            <button style="display: inline-block;"
                class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-active-color-primary down">
                <!--begin::Svg Icon | path: /var/www/preview.keenthemes.com/kt-products/docs/metronic/html/releases/2023-07-21-074234/core/html/src/media/icons/duotune/arrows/arr072.svg-->
                <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-3"><svg width="24"
                        height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path
                            d="M11.4343 12.7344L7.25 8.55005C6.83579 8.13583 6.16421 8.13584 5.75 8.55005C5.33579 8.96426 5.33579 9.63583 5.75 10.05L11.2929 15.5929C11.6834 15.9835 12.3166 15.9835 12.7071 15.5929L18.25 10.05C18.6642 9.63584 18.6642 8.96426 18.25 8.55005C17.8358 8.13584 17.1642 8.13584 16.75 8.55005L12.5657 12.7344C12.2533 13.0468 11.7467 13.0468 11.4343 12.7344Z"
                            fill="currentColor" />
                    </svg>
                </span>
                <!--end::Svg Icon-->
            </button>
            <button type="button"
                class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-active-color-primary delete"
                data-kt-element="remove-item">
                <!--begin::Svg Icon | path: icons/duotune/general/gen027.svg-->
                <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-3">
                    <svg width="24" height="24"
                        viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path
                            d="M5 9C5 8.44772 5.44772 8 6 8H18C18.5523 8 19 8.44772 19 9V18C19 19.6569 17.6569 21 16 21H8C6.34315 21 5 19.6569 5 18V9Z"
                            fill="currentColor" />
                        <path opacity="0.5"
                            d="M5 5C5 4.44772 5.44772 4 6 4H18C18.5523 4 19 4.44772 19 5V5C19 5.55228 18.5523 6 18 6H6C5.44772 6 5 5.55228 5 5V5Z"
                            fill="currentColor" />
                        <path opacity="0.5"
                            d="M9 4C9 3.44772 9.44772 3 10 3H14C14.5523 3 15 3.44772 15 4V4H9V4Z"
                            fill="currentColor" />
                    </svg>
                </span>
                <!--end::Svg Icon-->
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="border-bottom border-bottom-dashed rowToClone"
        id="rowToClone" type="product">
        <td class="pe-7 p-2">
            <select name="products[2]"
                aria-label="Sélectionnez un produit"
                data-placeholder="Sélectionnez un produit"
                class="form-select form-select-solid product">
                <option value="" selected>Sélectionnez un
                    produit/service</option>
                @foreach ($company->product_categories as $cat)
                    <optgroup label="{{ $cat->name }}">
                        @foreach ($company->products->where('product_category_id', $cat->id) as $p)
                            <option value="{{ $p->id }}"
                                price="{{ $p->price }}"
                                tax="{{ $p->tva }}">
                                {{ $p->name }}
                            </option>
                        @endforeach
                    </optgroup>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </td>
        <td class="ps-0 p-2">
            <input name="quantities[2]"
                class="form-control form-control-solid quantity"
                type="number" min="0" placeholder="1"
                value="0" data-kt-element="quantity">
        </td>
        <td class="p-2">
            <input type="text"
                class="form-control form-control-solid text-end price"
                name="prices[2]" placeholder="0.00" value="0.00"
                data-kt-element="price" readonly>
        </td>
        <td class="p-2">
            <input type="text"
                class="form-control form-control-solid text-end discount"
                name="discounts[2]" type="number" placeholder="0%"
                value="0" step="1" data-kt-element="discount">
        </td>
        <td class="p-2">
            <input type="text"
                class="form-control form-control-solid text-end tax"
                name="tvas[2]" placeholder="0" value="21"
                data-kt-element="tva">

        </td>
        <td class="pt-8 text-end text-nowrap p-2">
            <span class="subtotal" data-kt-element="total"
                id="subtotal">0.00</span>€
        </td>
        <td class="pt-5 p-2"
            style="width:100%;
        text-align: center;">
            <button style="display: inline-block;"
                class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-active-color-primary up">
                <!--begin::Svg Icon | path: /var/www/preview.keenthemes.com/kt-products/docs/metronic/html/releases/2023-07-21-074234/core/html/src/media/icons/duotune/arrows/arr073.svg-->
                <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-3"><svg width="24"
                        height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path
                            d="M12.5657 11.3657L16.75 15.55C17.1642 15.9643 17.8358 15.9643 18.25 15.55C18.6642 15.1358 18.6642 14.4643 18.25 14.05L12.7071 8.50716C12.3166 8.11663 11.6834 8.11663 11.2929 8.50715L5.75 14.05C5.33579 14.4643 5.33579 15.1358 5.75 15.55C6.16421 15.9643 6.83579 15.9643 7.25 15.55L11.4343 11.3657C11.7467 11.0533 12.2533 11.0533 12.5657 11.3657Z"
                            fill="currentColor" />
                    </svg>
                </span>
                <!--end::Svg Icon-->
            </button>
            <button style="display: inline-block;"
                class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-active-color-primary down">
                <!--begin::Svg Icon | path: /var/www/preview.keenthemes.com/kt-products/docs/metronic/html/releases/2023-07-21-074234/core/html/src/media/icons/duotune/arrows/arr072.svg-->
                <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-3"><svg width="24"
                        height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path
                            d="M11.4343 12.7344L7.25 8.55005C6.83579 8.13583 6.16421 8.13584 5.75 8.55005C5.33579 8.96426 5.33579 9.63583 5.75 10.05L11.2929 15.5929C11.6834 15.9835 12.3166 15.9835 12.7071 15.5929L18.25 10.05C18.6642 9.63584 18.6642 8.96426 18.25 8.55005C17.8358 8.13584 17.1642 8.13584 16.75 8.55005L12.5657 12.7344C12.2533 13.0468 11.7467 13.0468 11.4343 12.7344Z"
                            fill="currentColor" />
                    </svg>
                </span>
                <!--end::Svg Icon-->
            </button>
            <button style="display: inline-block;" type="button"
                class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-active-color-primary delete"
                data-kt-element="remove-item">
                <!--begin::Svg Icon | path: icons/duotune/general/gen027.svg-->
                <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-3">
                    <svg width="24" height="24"
                        viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path
                            d="M5 9C5 8.44772 5.44772 8 6 8H18C18.5523 8 19 8.44772 19 9V18C19 19.6569 17.6569 21 16 21H8C6.34315 21 5 19.6569 5 18V9Z"
                            fill="currentColor" />
                        <path opacity="0.5"
                            d="M5 5C5 4.44772 5.44772 4 6 4H18C18.5523 4 19 4.44772 19 5V5C19 5.55228 18.5523 6 18 6H6C5.44772 6 5 5.55228 5 5V5Z"
                            fill="currentColor" />
                        <path opacity="0.5"
                            d="M9 4C9 3.44772 9.44772 3 10 3H14C14.5523 3 15 3.44772 15 4V4H9V4Z"
                            fill="currentColor" />
                    </svg>
                </span>
                <!--end::Svg Icon-->
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```js
$("#cloneSection").click(function() {
    //Génère un ID aléatoire
    id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 999999) + 1);

    //Clone la section dans le tableau
    rowCloned = $("#sectionToClone").clone(true, true).insertAfter('#prods:last');

    //On récupère l'input section
    rowClonedSection = rowCloned.children().find('.section');

    //On récupère la row précédente
    prevRow = rowCloned.prev();

    //On récupère l'ordre de la row précédente
    prevRowType = prevRow.attr('type');
    if (prevRowType === 'section') {
        prevRowOrder = prevRow.children().find('.section');
        prevRowOrder = parseInt(prevRowOrder.attr('name').replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
    } else {
        prevRowOrder = prevRow.children().find('.product');
        prevRowOrder = parseInt(prevRowOrder.attr('name').replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
    }

    //On récupère le type de la row précédente
    prevRowType = prevRow.attr('type');

    //Génère l'ordre de la row clonée
    tempOrder = prevRowOrder + 1;

    //On attribue le numéro d'ordre à l'input section de la row clonée
    rowClonedSection.attr('name', 'sections[' + tempOrder + ']');

});
```

Comment: There is far too much code here. Create a [mre] and narrow down the problem. The usual pitfalls here are duplicated element IDs or dynamically generated elements not inheriting event listeners that were created at document load.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think i really understood what's the problem but if you want to add the cloned inputs inside the `<tbody>` you should use `#prods tr:last` insteade of `#prods:last`.
like this :

```
$("#sectionToClone").clone(true, true).insertAfter('#prods tr:last');
```